# iOS camera-based app for Facebook review

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, ios-simulator, ios-camera

My application is a camera based iOS application. I want to upload my application for Facebook review. But the review guidelines requires me to upload either simulator build file or AppStore link of the app. My application is not on the AppStore yet. I want to upload it only after it passes FB review procedure.

I cannot upload a simulator build file, as the app cannot run on the simulator because it uses camera.

Please suggest me some way so that I can upload my application for FB review.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can export an IPA for AdHoc deployment, which should allow them to install it on a device.

[image]

Then, select Export, which brings this up.

[image]

Then, select the AdHoc deployment option:

Save it at the location given, and then send that file to Facebook.

Comment: That is a good idea actually. But can I ask the review team to provide me with a device ID?....I am trying to find their contact email but no luck yet.